# Div captura o tamanho de outra

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Bom dia prezados(as), tenho um html e de vez em quando preciso inserir uma imagem que é uma "}" para determinar que em uma música irá repetir aquele trecho.

Como meu texto se adapta ao tamanho da tela, quando movimento ele muda de tamanho e a imagem é fixa, o que preciso é que ela se adapte ao tamanho do texto.

No planejamento que tive, comecei com uma ideia muito boa, deixei a div que possui o louvor sem `Height`, dessa forma ele fica automático, ficando na altura exata do texto. Se eu coloco a div onde está a chave sempre da mesma altura (até mesmo quando a outra é redimensionada).

Abaixo segue uma imagem onde destaquei as duas div's para entenderem melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso eu consiga de alguma maneira, deixo minha resposta, até lá, aceito qualquer ajuda ou ideia.

**CSS:**

```
#louvor{
        background-color: rgba(00,00,00,0.8);
        margin-left: 1%;
        width: 93%;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        font-size: 3.5vw;
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
        font-family: "Futura XBlk BT", Times, serif;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body id="principal">
        <div id="estrutura">
            <div id="logo-louvor"></div>
            <div id="louvor">           
            <font color="yellow">CORO:</font><br>
            AS MINHAS MÃOS TRAZEM CHAGAS TÃO FUNDAS<br>
            QUE TANTA AMARGURA EU PUDE ABRIGAR<br>
            DE TODA DOR DE VERGONHA E PECADO<br>
            EU FUI COROADO PARA TE SALVAR<br>
            </div>
            <div id="inform">
                <img src="../../imagens/chaves.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se possível coloque o que vc tem de HTML e CSS, pode ser que não precise de JS para fazer isso.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas é bem mais simples do que parece. Vou editar a postagem e inserir.

Comment: Alexandre você pode utilizar a propriedade min-height, height , min-width e width em porcentagem para a sua imagem, como também pode utilizar as css medias queries parra customizar em várias resoluções diferentes a exibição do quadro.

Comment: Rafael, não conheço sobre "css medias queries", vou ver a respeito, isso pode me ajudar sim.

Comment: Outra coisa, eu entendi que você deseja adicionar um background ao  fundo do texto louvor. Se for isso não precisa da imagem na div #inform, bastava utilizar o background-image na div #louvor. A tag font do HTML é obsoleta utilize a propriedade color direto no seu css para configurar a cor!

Comment: Ei Rafael, sobre a div <font> eu até sei que ela é obsoleta, mas é que tipo, são muitas músicas mesmo e vai ter todo um pessoal que vai me ajudar a escrever cada uma. 

Utilizei <font> direto no html, para criar uma coisa mais visível ao pessoal que vai me ajudar a escrever, afinal de contas só quero mudar a cor naquele exato nome "CORO" e na verdade quando tiver o nome "INSTRUMENTOS".

Comment: Sobre o que disse do background, não entendi. A div louvor eu quero ela transparente para pegar a imagem do body. Por isso setei background-color: rgba(00,00,00,0);

Answer (score 1):

consegui desenvolver algo que me atenda, vou publicar a resposta para que se alguém tenha dúvidas futuras e ache meu código viável, está a disposição.

Primeiro, dentro do meu HTML eu adicionei uma imagem normalmente:

```
<img class="chave-big" src="../../imagens/chaves.png">
            AS MINHAS MÃOS TRAZEM CHAGAS TÃO FUNDAS <br>
            QUE TANTA AMARGURA EU PUDE ABRIGAR<br>
            DE TODA DOR DE VERGONHA E PECADO<br>
            EU FUI COROADO PARA TE SALVAR<br>
```

Depois de forma muito simples, adicionei um css para a imagem:

```
.chave-big{
    height: 19vw;
    float: right;
}
```

Desta forma, estou utilizando um tamanho height com um valor responsivo "vw" e defini que a imagem terá o valor float para a direita, desta forma, ele acompanha meu texto no tamanho, porque meu texto também é responsivo baseado no "vw".

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Pessoal, estou com um problema que esqueci... O tamanho dessas chaves são relativos para cada música, como faço para determinar um tamanho para cada?

Comment: Existem algumas formas de fazer isso que pedi no comentário, acho que o que estou mais querendo é a boa prática de programação, acredito que, como terei vários itens com valores diferentes um dos outros a melhor maneira é definir a configuração da imagem inserindo o css no arquivo. 

Tópico pode ser fechado.

Answer (score 0):

Criei uma div qualquer, com um texto qualquer:

```
<div class="teste">
      Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e o
</div>
```

Então criei o seguinte código css, peguei uma imagem qualquer no google e coloquei como se fosse a sua chave, coloquei para ela não se repetir e do lado direito, para o texto não ficar por cima dela, coloque um padding a direita e coloquei para ela ficar de acordo com a altura da div.

```
.teste{
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 200px;
  background: url('https://teja8.kuikr.com/i6/20171219/After-1-year-of-use--it-is-still-going-well-VB201705171774173-ak_WBP1721615504-1513671149.jpeg') right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/r1rdznc3/1/

> Se você for utilizar este mesmo código css em mais de uma parte na
>   pagina, não utiliza id, utiliza classe.

Comment: Cara, ideia massa essa sua.. Colocando como background ele vai acompanhar o tamanho. 

Só tem um problema, esse que mandei na imagem é um exemplo, nem todos é o tamanho total do texto, alguns pedem apenas por exemplo as 3 últimas linhas. 

Mas ainda assim, acho que sua ideia pode funcionar, afinal se eu colocar no background o tamanho que quero ele vai sempre acompanhar as modificações. Vou tentar aqui, mas desde já. Muito obrigado.